# Correct way to create an ICMP request on Windows platforms

Tags: java, windows, java-native-interface, icmp

I'm trying to execute an ICMP request in Java on Windows. Initially I planned on using `InetAddress.isReachable()`. In the documentation it says:

> A typical implementation will use ICMP ECHO REQUESTs if the privilege can be obtained, otherwise it will try to establish a TCP connection on port 7 (Echo) of the destination host.

I know in Linux, you have to have root privileges to open a raw socket, therefore you need root privileges to ping. But is that the case in Windows?

I did some investigation and realized that maybe I should just use `runtime.exex(ping_command)`, but then I found some tools like [shortPasta](http://sourceforge.net/projects/shortpasta-icmp/)
or [Verax](http://www.veraxsystems.com/en/products/free-icmp-ping-library-java-windows) that are supposed to better implement ICMP requests in Java.
I noticed that both execute the ping binary like I wanted to do, but only in Linux; in Windows they used JNI.

I was wondering, is there some principal limitation for not executing the ping binary in Windows?

Comment: The limitation is likely to be that different OSes use different system calls and this library has been written for Linux.

Comment: Launching a subprocess is inefficient, so it makes sense to avoid doing so if possible.

Comment: @HarryJohnston So you're saying there's no principal limitation for executing the ping binary in Windows (efficiency aside)?

Comment: I don't really know what you mean by "principal limitation".  There is nothing *stopping* you from running the ping binary.  But it doesn't give you as much control as using the API, and it's a very awkward approach if you want to know what the *result* of the ping was.  You'd have to use a method that allows you to capture the output of the subprocess and then you'd have to parse it.  It also isn't forwards compatible, because the output isn't guaranteed to be the same between different versions of Windows.